# Google chrome has the wrong docky icon

Tags: chrome, icons, docky

I'm using fedora 20 with xfce.
The launcher icon on docky is the xfce panel icon instead of the google chrome icon, I've made sure the correct icon is inside /usr/share/applications but it's still the panel icon.

Comment: How did you install Chrome?

Comment: Downloaded it from www.google.com/chrome/‎, and installed it...

Comment: Edit your question and write the *exact procedures* you followed verbatim, in a way that anyone can reproduce.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, I was getting the google keep icon instead of chrome. It seems to be a common issue with Docky, see http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=How_to_Customize_Window_Matching

I simply followed their instructions, but to simplify:

1. run: `xprop | grep WM_CLASS | awk '{print $4}'`
2. This will give you a '+' shaped pointer. Use it to click on your Chrome window. It will output the name, I got 'Google-chrome'
3. Open `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` for editing and add `StartupWMClass=Google-chrome` or whatever you got in step 2 without quotes
4. stop Docky and run: `rm ~/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.*.cache`
5. Restart and the icon should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is click and drag the correct icon from the /usr/share/applications directory right into the dock. This eliminates duplicate icon conflicts, but if there is only one Google Chrome icon in this directory, and its .desktop file is titled google-chrome.desktop (like it was for me on a recent Chrome install), then you will need to save the .desktop file as google-chrome-stable and then drag this new .desktop file's icon into the dock.

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
sudo sed -i '/Group\]\|Desktop Entry/a StartupWMClass=Google-chrome-stable' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop && rm ~/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.*.cache
```

then restart docky and enjoy ([reference article](http://blog.steinwaywu.com/fix-duplicated-icons-in-plankdocky/)).